# How to create a select that depends on the value of another select?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a menu of regions hat display two lists: a `<select>` for the region and another `<select>` for the available municipalities of that region. For this, I have a `<form>` and I update the municipalities through JavaScript. I have problems assigning the municipalities as `<option>`s of the second `<select>`. The option matrix of the menu doesn't accept the assignment of the values.

Here's the code.

HTML.

```
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>
      P&aacute;gina men&uacute; principal.
    </title>
    <?!= incluirArchivo('ArchivoJS'); ?>
  </head>
  <body onLoad = "preparar();"> 
    <form id="formularioConductor" name="formularioConductor" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete = "on">

    <select name="menuDepartamento" id="menuDepartamento" tabindex="2" accesskey="e" onChange="municipiosDepartamento();">
     <option value="x" selected="selected">ELIJA UN DEPARTAMENTO</option>
     <option value="0">Antioquia</option>
     <option value="1">Atl&aacute;ntico</option>
    </select>
    <select name="menuMunicipios" id="menuMunicipios" tabindex="3" disabled>
                <option value=0>TODOS LOS MUNICIPIOS</option>
    </select>       
   </form>   
  </body> 
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script lenguage="javascript">
  function preparar() {
    document.forms[0].elements.numeroLicencia.focus();
    document.forms[0].elements.nombreConductor.disabled = true;
    document.forms[0].elements.botonEnviar.disabled = true;
    document.forms[0].elements.botonActualizar.disabled = true;      
  }

  function municipiosDepartamento() {
    var arregloMunicipiosDepartamento = new Array();
    var posicionMunicipio = document.forms[0].elements.menuDepartamento.value;
    arregloMunicipiosDepartamento = municipiosColombia(posicionMunicipio);
    if(document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.options.length > 1){
      var totalMunicipios = document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.length;
      for (var i = 1; i < totalMunicipios; i ++){
        document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.options[1] = null;
      }
    }
    if(document.forms[0].elements.menuDepartamento.value === "x"){
       document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.selectedItem = 0;
       document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.disabled = true;
    }
    else 
    {
      document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.options.length = arregloMunicipiosDepartamento.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arregloMunicipiosDepartamento.length; i ++) {
        var opcionTemporal = new Option(arregloMunicipiosDepartamento[i], (i+1));
        ***document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.options[i+1].text = opcionTemporal.text;
        document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.options[i+1].value = opcionTemporal.value;***
      }
      document.forms[0].elements.menuMunicipios.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  function municipiosColombia(posicion) {
    var antioquia, atlantico, arregloTodos, arregloMunicipiosDepartamento  = new Array();
    antioquia=["Medellín","Abejorral","Abriaqui","Alejandria"];
    atlantico = ["Barranquilla","Baranoa","Campo De La Cruz","Candelaria"];
    arregloTodos = [antioquia, atlantico];
    arregloMunicipiosDepartamento=arregloTodos[posicion];
    return arregloMunicipiosDepartamento;
  }
</script>
```

I have highlighted the work that doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The official language to use in this site for posting any content is English. I've translated the original content of your question with some technical terms in order to make it easier to read and understand. Please be aware of using English in the site. Also, your problem is related to **JavaScript**, not **Java**.

Comment: Luiggi: Lamento Mucho Haber consultado en español, no domino el ingles y no encuentro salida a Mi Problema. Mira lo que me responden es Prácticamente Lo Que él Hecho, Lo que no logro Hacer es que me acepte Estas Instrucciones:

Comment: document . forms [ 0 ]. elements . menuMunicipios . options [ i + 1 ]. text = opcionTemporal . text ; 
        document . forms [ 0 ]. elements . menuMunicipios . options [ i + 1 ]. value = opcionTemporal . value .

Comment: Tú me podrías colaborar con la redacción para ver si alguien sabe como logro que el arreglo de opciones me permita ampliar su dimensión. Es importante añadir que estoy en un sitio embebido en google y uso los servicios de google. Mil gracias y disculpa la molestia

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do what you describe is to clear out the options each time and recreate the required ones, then add them into the particular select, like so:

```js
var regions = {};
regions['A'] = ['mu', 'ni', 'ci', 'pal', 'it', 'y'];
regions['B'] = ['I', 'like', 'bananas'];

var selRegion = document.getElementById('region');

selRegion.onchange = setMunicipalities;

var selMun = document.getElementById('municipality');

function setMunicipalities(e)
{
  while(selMun.length > 0)
  {
    selMun.remove(0);
  }    
  if(selRegion.selectedOptions[0].value === 'ALL')
  {
    for(var r in regions)
    {
      if(regions.hasOwnProperty(r))
      {
        addMunicipalities(regions[r]);
      }
    }    
  }
  else
  {
    var reg = selRegion.selectedOptions[0].value;
    addMunicipalities(regions[reg]);
  }
}

function addMunicipalities(region)
{
  var allMun = document.createElement('option');
  allMun.setAttribute('value', 'ALL');
  var allMunText = document.createTextNode('ALL');
  allMun.appendChild(allMunText);
  selMun.add(allMun);
  for (var mi = 0; mi < region.length; mi++)
  {
    var m = region[mi];
    var mun = document.createElement('option');
    mun.setAttribute('value', m);
    var munText = document.createTextNode(m);
    mun.appendChild(munText);
    selMun.add(mun);
  }  
}

setMunicipalities(null);
```

```html
<label for="region">Region</label>
<select id="region">
  <option selected="selected" value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<label for="municipality">Municipality</label>
<select id="municipality">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your entire code because I had a hard time reading code with contents not in English but anyway, I get what you're trying to do here. Suppose that your first select list contains "Region A" and "Region B" as options; "Municipality A1", "Municipality A2", "Municipality B1","Municipality B2" are the possible options for the second select list. Here's a function that will change the options of the second select list depending on what is selected on the first select list:

```
    function optionChanger(v_selected){
          var whatisselected= v_selected.options[v_selected.selectedIndex].value;
          var municipalities= {};
          municipalities['A'] = ['Municipality A1','Municipality A2'];
          municipalities['B'] = ['Municipality B1','Municipality B2'];
          v_selected.options.length=0; //remove the contents of the second select list
          v_selected.options[0] = new Option(municipalities[whatisselected][0],municipalities[whatisselected][0],false,true);// set the first option of the second list as the default selected value
          for(x=1;x<municipalities[whatisselected].length;x++){ //add the remaining options to the second list
               v_selected.options[x] = new Option(municipalities[whatisselected][x],municipalities[whatisselected][x],false,false);
          }
  }
```

Then add this inside the tag of your FIRST select list:
        `onchange='optionChanger(this)'`
PS: Please notice that the return value of the first select list must be 'A', 'B'